# How to change basis for normal vector fields on regular surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, vector-fields, parametrization, change-of-basis

I have two normal vector fields over a surface $S$, to two parameterizations $\psi,\varphi$:

> $$X_{\psi}:p\mapsto X_{\psi}(p)=\dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial u}(\psi^{-1}(p))\wedge \dfrac{\partial \psi}{\partial v}(\psi^{-1}(p))$$
>
> $$X_{\varphi}:p\mapsto X_{\varphi}(p)=\dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial u}(\varphi^{-1}(p))\wedge \dfrac{\partial \varphi}{\partial v}(\varphi^{-1}(p))$$

At the intersection of the neighborhoods, $X_\psi,X_\varphi$ are related by matrix of coordinate changing, $g=\varphi^{-1}\circ\psi$. A professor wrote:

> $$X_{\psi}(q)=\det(Jg(\psi^{-1}(q)))X_{\varphi}(q).$$

I am confused with the transformations: I thought $g$ leads $Dom(\psi)$ to $Dom(\varphi)$, so why is not

> $$X_{\fbox{$\varphi$}}(q)=\det(Jg(\psi^{-1}(q)))X_{\fbox{$\psi$}}(q)?$$

Many thanks in advance for a light. If possible, I'd like not a yes/no answer, but some light to deal with this kind of transformation. Please take some look at the comments bellow. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function $h(x) = f(u)= f(g(x))$ where $u = g(x)$. Now, it is straightforward to see that $$\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i} = \frac{\partial h}{\partial u_j} \frac{\partial u_j}{\partial x_j} $$
 Notice that, while changing the variables from $x$ to $u$, the variables appear in the denominator i.e. $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x_i}$ and $\frac{\partial h}{\partial u_j}$.

Now coming to your question, $g=\varphi^{-1}\circ\psi$ and we are rather looking for how $\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial u}$ and  $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial u}$ are related. Notice that, unlike the previous case, the 'change of co-ordinates' happen in the numerator. Hence, it is the reverse of what you expected.

Update:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial  u} (\psi^{-1}(q)) & = \psi^{\prime}(\psi^{-1}(q))\times \frac{\partial \psi^{-1}(q)}{\partial  u} \\
 & = \psi^{\prime}(\psi^{-1}(q))\times \frac{\partial \psi^{-1}(\varphi (\varphi^{-1} (q)))}{\partial  u} \\
& = \psi^{\prime}(\psi^{-1}(q))\times {(\psi ^{-1})}^{\prime}(q) \frac{\partial (\varphi (\varphi^{-1} (q)))}{\partial  u} \\
& = \psi^{\prime}(\psi^{-1}(q)) \times \frac{1}{\psi^{\prime}(\psi^{-1}(q))} \frac{\partial (\varphi (\varphi^{-1} (q)))}{\partial  u} \qquad \text{(from the derivative of inverse function formula)} \\
& = \frac{\partial (\varphi (\varphi^{-1} (q)))}{\partial  u}
\end{align}

I am unable to get the multiplicative Jacobian factor in the final answer. May be someone can help.

Comment: many thanks for the attention! The question is a little bit confused, but your answer is very interesting. If it is interesting for you and you have time, I have on my profile some other unanswered questions on Differencial Geometry. Thank you. Best regards!

Comment: @Na'omi: I think my answer is wrong. I have been trying to solve this question and I think your conclusion seems right. I opened a new bounty and I hope someone will help both of us solve this question.

Comment: Many thanks for your honesty!

Comment: what do you mean by $\psi'$? Thank you!

Comment: @Na'omi: $\psi^{\prime}  = \frac{\partial \psi (\psi^{-1}(q) ) }{\partial \psi^{-1}(q) }$. Essentially, I am applying the chain rule.

Comment: Thank you once again.

Comment: @Na'omi: I am not sure if this application of chain rule for partial derivatives is correct in the first place. Also, notice that while I write $\psi^{\prime}$ as a single term, in case of multivariate input and output, this term would be a Jacobian.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking just about dimension when I asked you about $\psi'$... I hope someone could help us and once again thank you for attention.

Comment: I am reading this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526263/show-that-at-regular-surface-is-orientable-if-it-has-a-smooth-normal-vector-fiel. The author of post wrote "The change of coordinate matrix from $\{x_u^p,x_v^p\}$ to $\{y_u^p,y_v^p\}$ is $D(y^{-1}x)(x^{-1}(p))$, the Jacobian of $y^{-1}x$ evaluated at $x^{-1}(p)$." It seems that is as I thought (once the author wrote this as something that he studied). Now we have to prove... Thank you.

Comment: I unaccepted your answer just to the question get more attention and you do not lose your reputation bounty to no one, right? Otherwise someone can think the question is already finished. Thank you very much.